# Eclipse showing error in correct NamedQuery syntax

Tags: java, eclipse, persistence, jboss-tools

i have a problem with eclipse, i have this query that works fine using createQuery, but as i am converting all my "createQuery" to named queries i get this error:
[image]

The part of code where i wrote this:

```
(c.contaNumero || c.contaNumeroDigito)
```

is to concatenate two fields and match this concatenation with the user input.

As i said, this is a correct query, i just think eclipse or JBoss tools is showing an incorrect error message...
How can i solve this?

-------EDIT-------

I just found the answer to this, i posted it here but i can only accept it after 2 days from today (WTF?).

Comment: looool I like the title.. You are not even assuming that you might be wrong???????:)))))))))))))))

Comment: Maybe i am, i just assumed my syntax was right because THE SQL WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Ashish" said, hibernate only allows the use of operators like "||", but it is not on the JPQL syntax. So i just found that the function to concatenate it using JPQL was CONTATENATE(feld1, field2), if anyone have the same issue as me.

Answer (score 0):

|| is no operator in JPQL. Replace it with OR: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_operators

Comment: But this is not my objective, as i said, i want to concatenate these two fields into one,and match the input parameter with this concatenation. And about being a valid operator, it really is not, but with this exact sql executed by Session.createQuery, the code runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have error:

As mentioned by Mr. Ray `||` is not a operator in `JPQL` so you have to replace it with 'OR'

Why you are able to run is with session:

Hibernate allow `use arithmetic operators, concatenation, and recognized SQL functions in the select clause:` [mentioned here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Alright, but OR won't work as i expect... Anyway thanks for the answer but i just found what i needed, will put it on the answer myself.